# Use of subjunctive and presence of doubt

Tags: gramática, subjuntivo

Colón dijo: "Aunque tenga que buscarlos en las cárceles, los encontraré."

Why is the subjunctive for the verb tener used? Can't the indicative be used instead of the subjunctive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Aunque* can be followed either by subjunctive *or* indicative, with a subtle difference in meaning.

- *Aunque tengo que buscarlos en las cárceles, los encontraré*
  They are found in the jails, and although that may make things difficult, I shall find them.
- *Aunque tenga que buscarlos en las cárc5les, los encontraré*
  Whether or not I may need to search the jails, I shall find them.

Basically, if you use indicative, the clause is in fact true and integral to the non-aunque clause (and you could basically replace with "a pesar de que", or "in spite of" in English).

If you use subjunctive, you are saying that it's less important, or perhaps even non necessarily the case.  You can replace this with "Sea o no que..." or in English "even if".

Comment: doesn't aunque mean although?

Comment: Generally, yes.  But if I reuse *although* in both answers it can be confusing.  Another way to look at it is using subjunctive would, in the English, add the modal verb *may*.  *Aunque estudio/e mucho, nunca sacaré una A* --> "Although I (may) study a lot, I'll never get an A".  In one, you do study (indicative) and in spite of that studying, you won't get the A.  In the other (subjunctive or may in English), you're saying "even if / regardless if I study, I'll never get the A" and so maybe you will study, and maybe you won't.

Comment: Another subtle difference is between pretérito imperfecto and presente of subjuntivo: "Aunque tuviera que buscarlos en las cárceles...": but probably it won't be necessary. "Aunque tenga que buscarlos en las cárceles...": I don't know if it will be necessary. "Aunque tengo que buscarlos en las cárceles...", it is certainly necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It's not really a matter of 'doubt', but the dependent phrase expresses a hypothetical. You are not declaring that you are searching prisons.